# Merge Sort Implementation in C# - StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, mergesort

everyone!
I am trying to implement the merge sort algorithm in C#. And I have a StackOverflow Exception with my code.
I'm trying to figure out where is the problem and I can't solve it.

```cs
using System;

class MainClass {
  
  static void merge(int[] arr, int leftIndex, int endLeftIndex, int endRightIndex){
    // leftArr [leftIndex ... endLeftIndex]
    // rightArr [endLeftIndex + 1 ...  endRightIndex]
    int leftArrLength = endLeftIndex - leftIndex + 1;
    int rightArrLength = endRightIndex - endLeftIndex;
    
    int[] leftArr = new int[leftArrLength], rightArr = new int[rightArrLength];

    // Copying the data from the parent Array to the leftArr & rightArr
    for(int i = 0; i < leftArrLength; i++)
      leftArr[i] = arr[leftIndex + i];
    for(int j = 0; j < rightArrLength; j++)
      rightArr[j] = arr[endLeftIndex + j + 1];

    // the start index of the array that will be merged
    int mergedArrIndex = leftIndex;

    // set two start pointers for both left and right arrays
    int leftIndexMerge = 0, rightIndexMerge = 0;

    // the merging operation
    while(leftIndexMerge < leftArrLength && rightIndexMerge < rightArrLength){
      if(leftArr[leftIndexMerge] < rightArr[rightIndexMerge])
        arr[mergedArrIndex++] = leftArr[leftIndexMerge++];
      else
        arr[mergedArrIndex++] = rightArr[rightIndexMerge++];
    }
    
    // copying the rest elements
    while(leftIndexMerge < leftArrLength)
      arr[mergedArrIndex++] = leftArr[leftIndexMerge++];
    
    while(rightIndexMerge < rightArrLength)
      arr[mergedArrIndex++] = rightArr[rightIndexMerge++];
  }
  
  static void mergeSort(int[] arr, int leftIndex, int endRightIndex){
    if(leftIndex < endRightIndex){
      // leftArr [leftIndex ... m]
      // rightArr [m + 1 ...  endRightIndex]
      int m = leftIndex + (endRightIndex - 1) / 2;
      mergeSort(arr, leftIndex, m);
      mergeSort(arr, m + 1, endRightIndex);
      merge(arr, leftIndex, m, endRightIndex);
    }
  }
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1,2,5,10,1,2,3,4,4};
    mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.Length);
    foreach(int i in arr) Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
}
```

View the code in repl.it: https://repl.it/@MohamedMarzouk/MergeSortImplementationInCSharp

Comment: seems like you have an endless recursive call in mergeSort, did you step through already with the debugger?

Comment: No, I studied and understood the algorithm form geeksforgeeks website.
see the implementation in c++ here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had 2 problems

The first which caused your stack overflow

```
// int m = leftIndex + (endRightIndex - 1) / 2;
// should be
int m = leftIndex + (endRightIndex - leftIndex) / 2;
```

Looking at the source, you just mistook `l` for a `1`

[image]

and the following which would have given you an index out of range error

```
// mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.Length);
// should be
mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.Length-1);
```

No excuses there :)

Comment: This demonstrates the reason why you should never use `l` as a variable name!

Comment: @MatthewWatson indeed

Comment: The other bug demonstrates why the index of upper boundary should be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- the middle index computation is incorrect: `int m = leftIndex + (endRightIndex - 1) / 2;` should be

  ```
    int m = leftIndex + (endRightIndex - leftIndex) / 2;
  ```
- argument passed for the initial call from `Main` is incorrect: `mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.Length)` should be

  ```
    mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
  ```

This shows that the convention of including the starting and ending boundary indexes is error prone. If `endRightIndex` and `endLeftIndex`  are excluded, there is no longer a need for `+1` / `-1` adjustments.  I wish tutorials would stop teaching this non-sense.

Here is a simplified version:

```cs
using System;

class MainClass {
 
  static void merge(int[] arr, int leftIndex, int rightIndex, int endIndex) {
     // leftArr [leftIndex ... endLeftIndex)
     // rightArr [endLeftIndex ...  endIndex)
     int leftArrLength = rightIndex - leftIndex;
     int rightArrLength = endIndex - RightIndex;
   
     int[] leftArr = new int[leftArrLength];
     int[] rightArr = new int[rightArrLength];

     // Copying the data from the parent Array to the leftArr & rightArr
     for (int i = 0; i < leftArrLength; i++)
        leftArr[i] = arr[leftIndex + i];
     for (int j = 0; j < rightArrLength; j++)
        rightArr[j] = arr[rightIndex + j];

     // the start index of the array that will be merged
     int mergedArrIndex = leftIndex;

     // set two start pointers for both left and right arrays
     int leftIndexMerge = 0, rightIndexMerge = 0;

     // the merging operation
     while (leftIndexMerge < leftArrLength && rightIndexMerge < rightArrLength) {
        if (leftArr[leftIndexMerge] <= rightArr[rightIndexMerge])
           arr[mergedArrIndex++] = leftArr[leftIndexMerge++];
        else
           arr[mergedArrIndex++] = rightArr[rightIndexMerge++];
     }
   
     // copying the rest elements
     while (leftIndexMerge < leftArrLength)
        arr[mergedArrIndex++] = leftArr[leftIndexMerge++];
   
     // This final loop is actually redundant: these elements are already in place
     //while (rightIndexMerge < rightArrLength)
     //   arr[mergedArrIndex++] = rightArr[rightIndexMerge++];
  }
 
  static void mergeSort(int[] arr, int leftIndex, int endIndex) {
     if (endIndex - leftIndex >= 2) {
        // leftArr [leftIndex ... m)
        // rightArr [m ...  endIndex)
        int m = leftIndex + (endIndex - leftIndex) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, leftIndex, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m, endIndex);
        merge(arr, leftIndex, m, endIndex);
     }
  }

  public static void Main(string[] args) {
     int[] arr = { 1, 2, 5, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 };
     mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.Length);
     foreach (int n in arr)
        Console.WriteLine(n);
  }
}
```